# Please rename tag "python-kafka" to "kafka-python"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There are currently three main python libraries for Kafka:

1. [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python)
2. [pykafka](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka)
3. [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python)

Currently, there's a single [python-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-kafka) tag, with a description that explicitly refers to #1 (albeit with an old project link that 301's to a new location--I submitted a fix).

Can a moderator please rename the tag to `kafka-python` rather than `python-kafka` to reduce confusion/ambiguity?

Along those lines, it'd probably be good to also create tags for the other two projects so it's easier for users to tag which library they're using.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at all the 86 questions there and made sure that all of it refers to #1?

Comment: No. Even if they don't, leaving the tag as-is doesn't fix the problem that the tag description is explicitly about a single library, but the tag name is ambiguous between kafka-python and pykafka. An alternative is to make the tag description more general. However, I see no value in a more generic tag compared versus tagging a question with both `python` and `kafka`. So cleaning up the tag name prevents the confusion in the future and over time users (such as myself) will cleanup the confusion from the past.

Comment: [tag:pykafka] already exists. I just added [tag:confluent-kafka-python].

Comment: @BhargavRao do you have time to lookover my comment above?

Comment: Yeah, I've bookmarked this. I spent yesterday night going through the questions to check if anything needs re-tagging. I'll look into renaming it tonight. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I've renamed the tag after spending ample amount of time searching for wrongly tagged posts.

That is:

Removed [python-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-kafka) from 88 questions and added [kafka-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kafka-python) to 88 posts.

---

<sup>Adding this as answer so that we can remove this from the post of unanaswered questions.</sup>